# Registrando un dato en una tabla php-mysql-ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

tengo una tabla usuario la cual tiene un campo vacio, cuando intento realizar un update a al campo de la tabla me almacena los datos obtenidos de la sig manera  "? nR?!?s]5]?!??7M?z"

Comment: Parece que falta completar tu post, trata de editarlo en el boton editar. y lee [ask]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Cómo está definida la tabla usuario? Cómo ejecutas el update? Cómo consultas el dato insertado?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.